# Magento2 updating custom field in order creates new grid row

Tags: magento2, admin, order-grid

I've created a custom attribute in `Magento2` Order grid and sales_order table. Now when I am saving Order info using `OrderRepositoryInterface`, it creates a new blank row in order grid.

I am using     `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository` in my constructor and below is my code block

```
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($data['order_id']);
if ($order->getId() && $data['order_id']) {
    $order->setAtrributeName('4.4.1');
    $this->orderRepository->save($order);
}
```

Can someone tell me where I am doing wrong?